# Error validations from child model Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I got a problem which I can't solve. I made two models; one model called Film is the parent model and another model called Review is the child model. I got validation conditions on the child model but it does not display on the view.

Film model

```
class Film < ApplicationRecord
has_many :reviews

validates_presence_of :filmtitle,  presence: true
validates_presence_of :filmdescription,  presence: true
validates_presence_of :filmdirector,  presence: true
validates_presence_of :filmrating,  presence: true
validates_presence_of :filmstarname,  presence: true 
end
```

Review model

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
validates :rating,  presence: true
validates :commenter,  presence: true
validates :body,  presence: true
belongs_to :film
end
```

Review Controller

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @film = Film.find(params[:film_id])
    @review = @film.reviews.create(review_params)
    redirect_to film_path(@film)
end

private
def review_params
  params.require(:review).permit(:commenter, :body, :rating)
end
end
```

Film show.html.erb

```
  <% if @film.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
    <%= pluralize(@film.errors.count, "error") %></h2>
  <ul>
    <% @film.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
<%= form_for([@film, Review.new]) do |f| %>
<p>
 <%= f.label :commenter %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :commenter, :placeholder => 'Your name' %>
</p>
 <p>
 <%= f.label :body %><br>
 <%= f.text_area :body, :placeholder => 'Your comment' %>
 </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :rating %><br>
    <%= f.select :rating, ['1 Star', '2 Stars', '3 Stars', '4 Stars', '5    Stars'] %>
 </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
 <% end %>
```

Film Controller

```
class FilmsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_film, only: [:show]

# GET /films
# GET /films.json
def index
@films = Film.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 30)
@reviews = Review.new
end

# GET /films/1
# GET /films/1.json
def show
end

# GET /films/new
 def new

 end

 # GET /films/1/edit
def edit
 end

# POST /films
# POST /films.json
def create

end

# PATCH/PUT /films/1
# PATCH/PUT /films/1.json
def update

end

# DELETE /films/1
# DELETE /films/1.json
def destroy

end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_film
  @film = Film.find(params[:id])
end

 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list   through.
def film_params
  params.require(:film).permit(:filmtitle, :filmdescription)
end
 end
```

route.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :films do
resources :reviews
  end


  resources :rentals
  resources :buys
  resources :admin
  resources :adminrentals
   resources :adminfilms
   resources :logins
  resources :admins_login
   resources :games


    get '/adminCool' => 'admins_login#index'  

     get '/adminlogin' => 'admins_sessions#new'
     post '/adminlogin' => 'admins_sessions#create'  
     get '/adminlogout' => 'admins_sessions#destroy'

   get '/adminsignup' => 'admins#new'
     post '/admins' => 'admins#create'


  get '/login' => 'sessions#new'
 post '/login' => 'sessions#create'
 get '/logout' => 'sessions#destroy'

 get '/signup' => 'users#new'
 post '/users' => 'users#create'

 get '/cool' => 'logins#index'  



end
```

Comment: Why have you have tagged it with ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, and ruby-on-rails-3.2... is this an issue you are experiencing on all them versions? Where is your actual code for the controller?

Comment: Both controllers are mentioned above. Everytime it hits the render function, it direct me to the http://localhost:3000/films/18/reviews address. It suppose to go back to http://localhost:3000/films/18. I used the code given by Gaston (below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```
def create
    @film = Film.find(params[:film_id])
    @review = @film.reviews.new(review_params)
    if @review.save
      redirect_to film_path(@film)
    else
       render "films/#{@film.id}"
    end 
end
```

Comment: It doesn't display the error message but displays the blank results on the interface.

Comment: Doing the following produces the result Missing template films/show/#{@film} with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/azhan/Desktop/film_project/app/views" ??????

Comment: Sorry, was missing double quotes. Does render "films/show/#{@film.id}" works?

Comment: I still get the same error: Missing template films/show/16 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/azhan/Desktop/film_project/app/views" ?????????

Comment: where is show.html.erb located? in reviews or film's controller?

Comment: Its in the film controller

Comment: Keep getting the same error: Missing template films/11 with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/azhan/Desktop/film_project/app/views" ??????

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the answer, but in order to keep the error messages, yo have to re-render the same template (a redirect will wipe out the data). If you are following CRUD convention, you should be able to see the form by going to /films/:id. That's where I am trying to redirect upon failure. If I am not wrong, the error 'Missing template films/11' means you have no view show.html.erb in view/films . But you said you do, so I don't know what else could be failing. Please post your routes.rb

Comment: route.rb is displayed in the question.